# Redirecting to another page from a different flask microservice

Tags: javascript, html, flask, microservices

I'm currently building up a microservice architecture with flask. I've been trying to figure out how to redirect users from one service's UI to another service's UI. The services will be hosted on AWS upon completion so hardcoding links wouldn't suffice.

For example:
Submitting a form at localhost:8000/form will redirect the user to localhost:8001/anotherPage

Is there anything I can do within the html's javascript code or within flask python code?
Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is register an event in JavaScript

Then run the redirect command as

```
window.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com";
```

```js
function gohere(){
window.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com";
}


document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", gohere);
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">click here</button>
```

You could also call the even automatically on window load .JavaScript is by default the client side goto scripting for events

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Currently the example you've given has the hardcoded "http://www.w3schools.com". Is there a way to do it procedurally? The microservices will be deployed on AWS so the links will be different for each service.

Comment: Yes Just replace the hardcoded link "www" with a custom variable like 
var service = the_AWS_SERVICE
. You could also concatenate the service on the end of the URL if you need "www.aws.com"+service ;